# XSD mapping in Excel to generate multiples instances of XML elements

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

i'm using an XSD mapping in conjunction with excel in which i can insert information in order to generate an XML file. The problem is, the XSD mapping i'm using doesn't let me create multiple instances of an element. Here's my XSD code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="application">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="pagina">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:all>
                        <xs:element name="page_name" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="formulario" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:all>
                                    <xs:element name="textField" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="checkBox">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:all>
                                                <xs:element name="opcao" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                                            </xs:all>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:all>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>

                        <xs:element name="listagem" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:all>
                                    <xs:element name="entrada" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
                                </xs:all>   
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

            <xs:element name="escolha" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:all>
                        <xs:element name="origem" type="xs:string" /> 
                        <xs:element name="onSuccess" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="onFailure" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

For example, when i create the map in excel i can only create a single entry of information for "entrada", when in reality i would like to be able to add multiple entries of information of "entrada" for a single "listagem" element.

How can i map the information so i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `maxOccurs` and `minOccurs` will default to 1, allowing for only a single element.  You need to set `maxOccurs` to `unbounded` or an explicit value.

```
<xs:element name="entrada" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string" />
```

Comment: When i add maxOccurs="unbounded" to the "pagina" element i get "Cannot load the specified XML schema". For some reason, Excel doesn't like when i add maxOccurs="unbounded" to any of the elements.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  That would be the solution for xsd alone but that's not the way excel maps work apparently.  I'd find an Excel schema that allows for multiplicity and then steal the piece that does that, or create a sample XML file that has an example of what you need and use the Excel mapping generation tooling.

Comment: I'm trying to find an example of that, but i'm not being lucky.

Comment: Your best first step would be to try the tooling.  It appears as though that is the MS recommended way.  Even the more technical information about generating mapping files appears to advocate the use of scripts that generate the schema rather than manual creation/modification (keep something transparent relatively opaque).
This post mentions getting a schema that should at least be able to be stolen from if not used directly:
http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=248297